# Cassandra update vs insert. How to set a column to null [using insert]?

Tags: cassandra, spring-data-cassandra

Cassandra insert is kind of update except the fields which are being overwritten. If those are `null` it will keep the old values and will not overwrite it with `null`.

Example: Table t1 with `x`, `y` columns using `x` as primary key.

Data: `x= "xxx" y ="yyy"`

`INSERT (x,y) VALUES ("xxx", "zzz")` will work fine. `UPDATE
(x,y) VALUES("xxx")` will not set `y` to `null`.

I am using Spring Data Cassandra which has Repositories. Repositories don't have methods to update it just a method to create. When I try to explicitly set value `null`, it skips those value and insert is not working exactly like update.

How can I set `null` values using Spring Data Cassandra values while insert?

Comment: You can call delete on that specific column if you want no value for it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Spring Data Cassandra skips currently (in version `1.4.1.RELEASE`) `null` values on `insert(…)` and `update(…)`. Your current only option is using plain CQL in that case. We have an [open ticket](https://jira.spring.io/browse/DATACASS-182) to allow insertion of `null` values.